# How would I play a sound when the collision occurs?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to flash and using as3. I am in the process of making a simple catching game where the items fall from the top and you control a basket at the bottom to catch them. My script is fine and is playing without erros throughout which I am happy about, but how would I add a sound clip to this script to play when the item lands in the basket? Thanks in advance!!!

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

var catcher:Catcher;
var createEnemyID:uint;
var gameSpeed:uint;
var droppedText:TextField;
var caughtText:TextField;
var score:uint=0;

function initGame():void{
    catcher=new Catcher();
    catcher.x=500;
    catcher.y=1400;
    addChild(catcher);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,moveCatcher);
    Mouse.hide();
    gameSpeed=500;
    createEnemyID=setInterval(createEnemy,gameSpeed);
    droppedText=new TextField();
    droppedText.x=50;
    droppedText.y=50;
    addChild(droppedText);
    caughtText=new TextField();
    caughtText.x=250;
    caughtText.y=50;
    addChild(caughtText);
    droppedText.text=caughtText.text='0';
}

function moveCatcher (e:MouseEvent):void{
    catcher.x=this.mouseX;
    e.updateAfterEvent();
}

function createEnemy():void{
    var enemy:Faller=new Faller();
    enemy.y=-1;
    enemy.x=Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;
    enemy.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropEnemy);
    addChild(enemy);
}

function dropEnemy(e:Event):void{
    var mc:Faller=Faller(e.target);
    mc.y+=15;
    if(mc.hitTestObject(catcher)) {
        caught(mc);
    }

     else if (mc.y>stage.stageHeight){
         dropped(mc);
     }
}

function caught(mc:Faller):void{
    mc.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,dropEnemy);
    removeChild(mc);
    caughtText.text=String(Number(caughtText.text)+1);
}


function dropped(mc:Faller):void{
    mc.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,dropEnemy);
    removeChild(mc);
    droppedText.text=String(Number(droppedText.text)+1);

    if(droppedText.text=='5'){
        gameOver();


    }

}

function gameOver():void{
    score=Number(caughtText.text);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,moveCatcher);
    removeChild(catcher);
    clearInterval(createEnemyID);
    removeChild(caughtText);
    removeChild(droppedText);
    while(numChildren>0){
        getChildAt(0).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dropEnemy);
        removeChildAt(0);
    }
    Mouse.show();
    gotoAndStop('gameover');
}

initGame();
```

Comment: Have you tried web searching?  There are no shortage of tutorials online about playing sounds in flash.

Answer (score 1):

import the sound into flash.
edit the properties and set the class of the sound to MySoundClass or whatever you like but you have to reference it later.
In your code write the following in the collision method.

```
var sound:Sound = new MySoundClass(); 
sound.play();
```

See this [AS3 Sound tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/)